# LAN8720 ETH Board - PCB Board has a "cut out" area - Could someone explain why?

Tags: pcb

As I was looking at my [LAN8720](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07BFPFYGZ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1) ETH Board I noticed that there is a distinc "cut" between the ususal everything flat ground.
Here is a [picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_9Ul1qPt6ZlWdHffBIaY3jzUA87BsNGr/view?usp=sharing) to show what I mean.
Usual on a PCB Board the layer as I know is "flat" with the only the trace as small "cuts" as seen in the picture next to the circles or close to the clock.

Now I see 2 "cuts" (yellow circle) between the ground layer (I suppose) and the whole area in the green circle seems to be in a complete "cut out" with only the traces sticking out this time

Could someone explain to me what the reason behind this design is ?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ethernet interfaces are galvanically isolated via transformer coupling.

There must be no direct connection between cable side ground (i.e. connector chassis) and your PCB ground (i.e. ground plane, return path for power supplies).

Sometimes the ground plane is removed under the Ethernet signals to have less stray capacitance between Ethernet signals and ground.

This allows the Ethernet connection to withstand large potential difference between two devices, about 1000 volts.

Comment: Thanks. I could understand that. I have another Ethernet Board that works over SPI that doesn't do that. Also now I would like to design my own LAN8720 plus RJ45 Jack onto a more complex board but it seems hard to do. Is it mandatory to do that or just good ?